# Local HTML file does not show properly in WebView with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a simple HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script async src="https://URL"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="class-name"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I access it with a browser using Windows: `C:\foo.html?q=query` the file loads correctly.

When I access the same file, that I have added it to my `Android` project in the `Assets` directory, with a `Custom WebView` and a `Custom Renderer` in my Xamarin.Forms project like this: `myCustomWebview.Uri = "foo.html" + "?q=" + queryString;` the Javascript fails to populate the `div` in the `body` correctly. The same problem exists if I load the file without a query string: `myCustomWebview.Uri = "foo.html";`

What's the deal? Do I need to set any special `Permissions` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the Javascript to work properly? Do I need to set a specific `BuildAction` in the file properties of the HTML file in my Android project? Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Place `html` file into `Assets` directory with build action `AndroidAsset` .
2. Use `DependencyService` to set the exact path .

   ```
   [assembly: Dependency (typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
   namespace WorkingWithWebview.Android
   {
       public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
       {
           public string Get()
           {
               return "file:///android_asset/";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set `BaseUrl`  to `HtmlWebViewSource` and pass it to `WebView.Source` .

   ```
   var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
   source.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
   webView.Source  = source .
   ```

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content.

Comment: I did it and I'm getting a blank page. The only difference is that I have my HTML file in `Assests/Content`, but I changed the relative line to `return "file:///android_asset/Content";` By the way, how do I pass the query string in your implementation? I have a variable with it. And my final question, what about the `Uri` property from the `Custom Renderer`? Is it useless in this scenario?

Comment: Well, I succeeded loading the file by changing the last line of your code to `webResults.Uri = source.BaseUrl + "foo.html";`
The file loads, but it again loads incorrectly. I'm afraid it has something to do with the Javascript and not the way of accessing it.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#invoke-c-from-javascript , maybe helpful .

Comment: I think I have a lead, but I still am not sure how to deal with it. From the Debugging output:  `[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://play.google.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.", source: file:///android_asset/Content/foo.html (0)`

Any idea?

Comment: It seems something problem would happen if trying to access the js inside a local html file , need to research on this .

Comment: Undoubtedly. I used an alternative as a solution. I use an online version of the page in my code and I edit it by injecting my own Javascript, so I gave a solution without dealing with that particular problem.

Comment: As I said, my solution was to load an online version of the HTML file, similar to the one I had implemented locally, and then edit some parts by injecting JS code using a `Custom Renderer`. That's a solution that worked for me, but it's not a solution to the original problem. It's a workaround. I don't think it qualifies to get posted as an answer.